# How to count rows from a Mysql result?

Tags: php, mysql

i have tried alot and this is my last code. Any ideas how i can get this work?

```
$id_name = $this->name->Text;
    $finder = prdtblRecord::finder();
    $result = $finder->findAllByname($id_name);
    $row_cnt =  $result->num_rows;
```

Comment: What are you exactly looking for? For the function `findByid()` ? If not, pelase edit your question and try to be more precise, since its quite dofficult to understand what you exactly want.

Comment: I'm looking for a function that looks if the id on the formular is existent.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a query that checks if the id you have exists or not

```
$sql = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME WHERE id = TO_CHECK_ID )"
```

then you could do something like

```
$id = mysql_query($sql);
if($id)
    echo "success"; //your code upon success
else
    echo "failed"! //your code upon failure
```

hope this helps

Comment: Please don't use this function. First of all, `mysql_*` driver is deprecated and not lnoger supported in PHP7. Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_*`` instead. Also, if your ID is coming from a user input, please use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections. You can learn more about how to use them here http://bobby-tables.com